# Are there breaking changes in model binding of collections in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, model-binding

Ok, so after migrating from MVC3 to MVC4 I ran into interesting problem.
We had a controller method with following signature:

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid[] items)
```

This worked great in MVC3 but stopped working after upgrade to MVC4 - the items array is always empty. I realized that in MVC4 I would have to use ICollection instead to make it work:

```
public ActionResult Delete(ICollection<Guid> items)
```

Is that a breaking change? Or the first approach is not really a proper way of doing things that just worked as a fluke in MVC3?

The data that is posted looks very simple and looks like this:

```
items=52b37b94-1f53-4981-a698-9eb6eca30861&items=d2f8c5e5-4e04-4a97-8efd-643a4e87e48b
```

And is posted using jQuery ($.post)

Comment: Are you posting via jquery?

Comment: That is correct. I'll update the question

Comment: The array should still work, have you tried adding this property to your jquery call? `traditional: true`

Comment: We are still using jQuery 1.7 (I believe default value of traditional changed in 1.8), so that should not be an issue, I'll try it though.

Comment: MVC4 in VS 2012 uses jQuery 1.8.2 by default.

Comment: That's right, but we stayed on purpose with 1.7 during upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was happening. I started brand new MVC4 project to create a vanilla test case, and binding worked properly for both array and collection of Guids.

After digging I realized that during upgrade we also upgraded autofac DI container from version 2.5 to 3.0. Some internals may have changed and action injection got enabled by default.

Apparently action injection was interfering with model binding.